# Busca intervalo datas Laravel/Eloquent?

Tags: php, lavarel

Como pesquisa o intervalo de datas?

Pesquisei e muitos lugares indicam a forma de busca de intervalos de data conforme exemplo abaixo, mas sem resultado.

```
$d1 = data2Mysql($dataI); // format Y-m-d
$d2 = data2Mysql($dataF); // format Y-m-d

$current = DB::table('ponto')
        ->whereBetween('data_inicial',[$d1,$d2])
        ->first();
```

O `Eloquent` monta corretamente a SQL, mas o resulto é `null` e existem dados na tabela onde o intervalo está sendo pesquisado.

Query executada:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(66) "select * from `ponto` where `data_inicial` between ? and ? limit 1"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-12"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-13"
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(0.95)
  }
}
NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um colega de equipe me passou um exemplo em outra linguagem e usando um `whereRaw` do `eloquent` consegui o resultado esperado e estou compartilhando:

```
   $d1 = data2Mysql($dataI); // format Y-m-d

    $current = DB::table('ponto')
        ->whereRaw('? between data_inicial and data_final', $d1)
        ->first();
```